# My Gloves are Impossible to Weight Paint

Tags: animation, rigging

what's the best/easiest way to rig/weight paint a glove shaped like this? There are many objects overlapping each other to create this shape (like a boxers glove). I tried rigging with automatic weights and there's so many problems to fix that I'm wondering if there's a better way. I joined all the objects to make them one so it's a little easier, but still can't figure it out. It is even possible to rig these type of gloves in a reasonable timeframe the way my topology is flowing and have it look good when the fingers bend? Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: If you connect faces on the inside of your mesh, assigning automatic weights works a lot better. You have to merge vertices or create new faces though, just connecting 2 vertices with a new edge doesn't work. It's a lot of manual work and not perfect unfortunatly.

Comment: That's a good idea, thanks!